# How to see that $l^{1}(\mathbb{Z}) \to C(S^1, \mathbb{C}): a \mapsto \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}a_n z^n$ is not surjective?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-series

Consider the map $$l^{1}(\mathbb{Z}) \to C(S^1, \mathbb{C}): a \mapsto (z \mapsto \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}a_n z^n)$$

I want to show that this is not surjective.

I don't see which element I should take in the codomain that does not get attained.
I feel like this somehow has a connection with basic Fourier theory. Thanks in advance!

Comment: My first thought was to try the Open Mapping Theorem - can't quite see how to apply it, though, I'm a bit rusty on that.

Comment: There are lots of continuous functions with Fourier series that are not absolutely convergent (easy one is $\sum_{n\ge 2}{\frac{\sin nx}{n \log n}}$)

Comment: Please give the definition of $\ell^1(\mathbb Z)$.

Comment: @Paul Frost. It is the set $\{(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}:\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} |a_n|<\infty\}$ where the summation is understood as in this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3563674/show-sum-n-in-mathbbz-sum-k-in-mathbbz-a-k-b-n-k-zn-sum-n

Comment: And of course $a_n \in \mathbb C$.

Comment: Yes, that's right!